# ec2 ami for rails 3.1 apache passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there an ec2 ami available with

- apache
- passenger
- rails 3.1

preferably ubuntu or fedora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than look for an AMI with the software pre-installed, simply run an official Ubuntu server AMI and install the standard Ubuntu packages for the software you want.

It's probably as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get upgrade &&
sudo apt-get install apache2 ...
```

Then tweak configuration and add your content / application.

If you are trying to run a version of software more recent than the one provided with the official release, then you may need to do a bit more work.

Remember to document / script exactly how you create the instance so that you can do it again in the future when you need to.